Use of conditionals with group_by
I have a dataframe XYdata and I need to count per participant (ppt) and item (item) if there is any value in column Time (Time). If there is no value there, it means that all rows for that participant and item are NAs. The result needs to go in a table with N_NAs and N_Values as columns, like the following:
Desired output:
|ppt         |item   |N_NAs |N_Values|
|------------|-------|------|--------|
|ppt1        |1      |0     |1       | #there was a value
|ppt1        |2      |1     |0       | #there was no value, only NAs
|ppt1        |3      |1     |0       | #there was no value, only NAs
|ppt1        |4      |0     |1       | #there was a value

Although I could count how many NAs there are per participant and item:
XYdata2 <-XYdata %>% group_by(ppt, item) %>% summarise(sum_na_Time = sum(is.na(Time)))

and then calculate if that is the total number of rows I should expect per participant and item, I prefer to use if or a conditional to calculate this.
Example of XYdata
XYdata<- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 40)), c("item","Time", "ppt")) 
XYdata$item <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4") 
XYdata$Time <- c("","","","","1.456","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3.722","","","","","")
XYdata$ppt <- c(" ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1", " ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1"," ppt1", " ppt1")


Maybe use if_else? R’s if is a flow control function. For this question you need a larger example and a specification of the exact desired output.

@IRTFM could you put in an answer how you would use if_else please?

I do not understand the question you are asking. If you are creating the table above, then the sum of the columns N_NAs and N_Values will give you the number of observations per participant-item combination. To @IRTFM's point, we need a minimum working example of the input data and the exact desired output.

@mikebader Example added

Depending on how your data is structured, you could first use ifelse() and then ddply() from the plyr package to summarize all the values.
There is a shorter code for it, but I don't know it but something like this could work:
library(plyr)

#add new column and add 1 for every empty column in XYdata$Time and 0 if there is a value
XYdata$N_NAs <- ifelse(XYdata$Time == ' ', 1, 0)
    
#add new column and add 0 for every empty column in XYdata$Time and 1 if there is a value
XYdata$N_Values <- ifelse(XYdata$Time == ' ', 0, 1)
    
#add up all the values for each ppt per item 
results <- ddply(XYdata, .(ppt, item), nrow)


I'm still not sure that I understand where you want to use if_else(). If I do understand correctly, then you can create a variable that contains information about whether time is missing or not (time_mi) below, and then you can summarize the number of times those two values are true within each group.
XYdata %>% 
    mutate(time_mi = if_else(Time == "", "NA", "Value")) %>% 
    group_by(ppt, item) %>% 
    summarize(
        N_NAs = sum(time_mi == "NA"),
        N_Values = sum(time_mi == "Value")
    )

Result:
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   ppt [1]
  ppt     item  N_NAs N_Values
  <chr>   <chr> <int>    <int>
1 " ppt1" 1         9        1
2 " ppt1" 2        10        0
3 " ppt1" 3        10        0
4 " ppt1" 4         9        1


Thanks @mikebader. Instead of how many NAs though, I would like to have in the output only if there was any value or if there wasn't. So an output of 0s and 1s.
